# neo4j Creating many relationships with individual statements much slower than a loop

Tags: neo4j

I have 2 queries in neo4j

```
MERGE (f:Foo {id:1}) 
MERGE (b:Bar {id:1}) 
with f,b 
FOREACH (i IN range(0,999) | create (f)-[:Qux]->(b));
```

> Added 2 labels, created 2 nodes, set 2 properties, created 1000 relationships, statement executed in 39 ms.

and

```
MERGE (f:Foo {id:1}) 
MERGE (b:Bar {id:1}) 
with f,b 
CREATE (f) - [:Qux] -> (b)
CREATE (f) - [:Qux] -> (b)
... (1000 times)
CREATE (f) - [:Qux] -> (b)
```

> Added 2 labels, created 2 nodes, set 2 properties, created 1000 relationships, statement executed in 8301 ms.

**How come it is so much slower to create relationships with statements than with a loop?**

I want to be able to create many relationships at once but a loop isn't appropriate as I want to include data on each individual relationship. How could I do this fast *without* using a loop. I assume something about my syntax is making a wrong assumption.

**NOTE:** i cleared the graph before running each of these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely want to use an iterative loop still, because then the DB only has to parse a single `CREATE` statement and re-use it (iteration is native to Java, so it's easy to translate a request to iterate to fast queries). If you need to assign properties to each relationship, unwind the list of properties instead of the `RANGE()`.

```
UNWIND {r_props} AS r_prop
CREATE (f) - [r:Qux] -> (b)
SET r = r_prop
```

Or if you need to calculate properties per-relationship based on a query, unwind the RANGE and you can do the full set of Cypher operations (`MATCH`, etc.) per relationship:

```
UNWIND range(0, 999) AS i
CREATE (f) - [r:Qux] -> (b)
MATCH (n:OtherNode {id: i})
SET r = PROPERTIES(n)
```

Using `FOREACH` is convenient but can be limiting. You'll still want an iterative loop either way, though, because it's always going to be quicker for `neo4j` to interpret.

Comment: So does the extra time essentially come from query parsing?

Comment: Not just parsing, it's also faster to execute the resulting code and lighter in memory, because that's how it would be if you translated the query into Java manually. The planner won't pick up on the iterative aspect of your code, so you'll lose all the potential for optimization.

Comment: Yeah this seems heaps faster, much appreciated